# Rake task aborted, undefined method 'indexes' for Thinking Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx 2.0.5 installed on my application and when I keep trying to run the command `rake ts:index` it gives me this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `indexes' for #<Riddle::Configuration:0x41b57b0>
```

Is is talking about my `Product` model?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates_presence_of :name

  define_index do
    indexes :name
  end
end
```

Why I am getting this  and how do I fix it?

Comment: We can't know if it is talking about the Product model. Did you try running `rake ts:index --trace`? You will get a stacktrace that way.

Comment: @Wukerplank Ok I ran `rake ts:index --trace` and here is my https://gist.github.com/1345070 so you can look at it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to what is written here: https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/issues/301

In your Gemfile try changing:

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.5'
```

to

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10'
```

Answer (score 1):

in my Gemfile I was having entry as

gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.3'

I was getting same error. Then I changed it to

gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10'  and issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Man, you can try go to the Gemfile.lock e look for those lines:

```
riddle (1.5.0)
thinking-sphinx (2.0.5)
   activerecord (>= 3.0.3)
   builder (>= 2.1.2)
   riddle (>= 1.5.0)
```

If you read again the error you will see that is the Riddle launching error not sphinx.

```
*undefined method `indexes' for #<Riddle::Configuration:0x41b57b0>*
```

I have a project working perfectly with thinking-sphinx 2.0.5 and in the Gemfile.lock the sphinx is requiring the riddle version 1.3.3 or older so in the project that the same thinking-sphinx isn't working I changed my riddle version in gem file from 1.5.0 to 1.3.3 using thinking-sphinx 2.0.5 and the problem was solved. The sphinx version 2.0.10 works fine with riddle 1.5.0 so you have to choose if you want to change the Thinking-sphinx Gem version or the Riddle version on Gemfile.lock to:

```
riddle (1.3.3)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
thinking-sphinx (2.0.5)
  activerecord (>= 3.0.3)
  riddle (>= 1.3.3)
```